# Remembering that $\sin^2(\theta) = 1/2 - 1/2\cos(2\theta)$?

Tags: trigonometry, mnemonic

How do you remember this for integrals?

It doesn't seem obvious and I can never remember it when I come across it in integrals.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "remember this for integrals" ?

Comment: When you're doing the integral of $sin^2(\theta)$, it seems the answer is to replace it with the above linear form, so it's easier to integrate.

Comment: @user3139573 Please let me know how I can improve my answer.

Answer (score 5):

The double angles should be remembered as follows,

\begin{align*}
2\sin^2 (\theta) &= 1 - \cos(2\theta) \\
2\cos^2 (\theta) & = 1 + \cos(2 \theta).
\end{align*}

To know which sign for each, remember that 'sinning' is bad, hence it leads to $-$.

Reason why you should memorize like this is because there no fractions and you can see a pattern!

When you need to compute the integral of say, $\sin^2 (\theta)$, just recall formula and divide by $2$.

Comment: +1 for "'sinning' is bad". It also beats the pants off of my suggestion of "tattooing on the inside of one's eyelids".

Comment: Should it not be "2 sin is bad?"

Comment: @Dr.MV Yes, that is better!

Comment: Much better than any mnemonic: just insert $\theta=0$, and then it will be obvious which one is which...

Comment: Sinning is bad, thanks. I have an alternative: if you have the same function both sides then +, otherwise -

Answer (score 4):

HINT:

I remember the identity by first remembering the addition formula:

$$\cos (x+y)=\cos x \cos y-\sin x \sin y \implies \cos (2x) =1-2\sin^2 x$$

Comment: Was going to put this method myself. The addition formulae were always what I always remembered, most others could be derived from these.

Comment: @bburGsamohT  I agree.  One can derive a great many identities from the addition formulae.

Comment: Okay... but how do you remember the formula for the cosine of sum?

Comment: @HomegrownTomato One could ask how does one remember anything at all.  I have found the addition formulae extraordinarily useful and worth retaining.  To answer "how," are you asking if there is a specific pneumonic methodology I use?  If so, then "no," there is no unusual pneumonic here.

Comment: The point is, you haven't answered the question.

Comment: @HomegrownTomato Well, I hinted as to how I remember the identity that the OP has posted.  I remember it by first remembering the addition formula. Make better sense now?

Answer (score 2):

here is a geometric way to remember the double angle formulae. we will use the fact that on the unit circle the terminal point corresponding to the arc length $t$ is $(\cos t, \sin t).$

look at the arc of length $2t$  starting at $A = (1,0)$ and ending at $B = (\cos 2t , \sin 2t)$ the midpoint $C$ of $AB$ has coordinate $((1+\cos 2t)/2, \sin 2t/2).$ but the length $OC$ is $\cos t.$

now the point on the unit circle cut by $OC$ can be seen in two ways:

$$a: (\cos t, \sin t), \quad b: \left(\frac{1+\cos 2t}{2\cos t}, \frac{\sin 2t}{2\cos t}\right)$$

equation the two gives the double angle formula $$1+\cos 2t = 2\cos^2 t, \sin 2t = 2\sin t \cos t $$

Comment: I really like this geometric proof as an easy way to derive the double angle formulae.  I do think, however, that it is a bit easier just to remember the addition angle formulae and derive the double angle as a special case.  Any way, +1.

Comment: @Dr.MV, thanks for the upvote. of course if one knows the addition formula, then making two arguments the same gives you the double angle formula. i am trying to do the double angle formula as a stand alone result.

Answer (score 2):

If I want to recall the formulas
$|\sin \frac x2| = \sqrt{\frac{1-\cos x}2}$ and 
$|\cos \frac x2| = \sqrt{\frac{1+\cos x}2}$ 
and if I already remember the form $$\sqrt{\frac{1\pm\cos x}2}$$ but I do not remember which sign corresponds to sine and which to cosine, I can recall it like this:

If $x$ is close to $0$, then $\cos x$ is close to $1$. I want to get the value of $\sin(x/2)$, which is close to $0$, which I get from $1-\cos x$. Similarly, I want to get $\cos(x/2)$ close to $1$, to get this, I take $1+\cos x$.

But I agree that probably the better way is to recall how the formulas were derived from the double angle formulas.

Answer (score 1):

Its easy to remember cos(2x) = cos<sup>2</sup>x - sin<sup>2</sup>x
and then use cos<sup>2</sup>x + sin<sup>2</sup>x = 1 to get the required identity

Answer (score 1):

$\cos^2 \theta + \sin^2 \theta = 1$
$\cos^2 \theta - \sin^2 \theta = \cos 2\theta$

Add and you get
$2\cos^2 \theta = 1 + \cos 2\theta$
$\cos^2 \theta = \frac 1 2 + \frac 1 2\cos 2\theta$

Subtract and you get
$2\sin^2 \theta = 1 - \cos 2\theta$
$\sin^2 \theta = \frac 1 2 - \frac 1 2\cos 2\theta$

Answer (score 0):

Here's a longer explanation, which maybe will make the identity seem a bit more obvious:

As you know, a **cosine wave** oscillates between $-1$ and $+1$ with a period of $2 \pi$.
Here are some of the values:
$$
\cos 0=+1
,\quad
\cos(\pi/2) = 0
,\quad
\cos\pi = -1
,\quad
\cos(3\pi/2) = 0
,\quad
\cos(2\pi) = +1
.
$$
Compare this to the values you get if you square everything:
$$
\cos^2 0=+1
,\quad
\cos^2(\pi/2) = 0
,\quad
\cos^2\pi = +1
,\quad
\cos^2(3\pi/2) = 0
,\quad
\cos^2 2\pi = +1
.
$$
So a **cosine-squared wave** oscillates between $0$ and $+1$, and it makes two oscillations where the cosine wave makes only one, so it oscillates twice as fast.

In fact, it's a perfect sin/cos-wave shaped oscillation. Of course, this isn't obvious just from sampling a few values, but it's true; that's what the double-angle formula is saying. Try plotting it on a computer, and you'll see that it certainly looks that way!

So it must be oscillating around its average value $1/2$ with an amplitude of $1/2$ (so that it precisely reaches up to its maximum value $1$ and reaches down to its minimum value $0$).

Thus, you get the cosine-squared wave by taking a cosine wave $\cos 2\theta$ (with twice the frequency compared to $\cos \theta$), multiplying it by the amplitude factor $1/2$, and then adding $1/2$ to shift the graph upwards:
$$
\cos^2 2 \theta = \frac12 + \frac12 \cos 2\theta
.
$$
And the formula for the sine-squared that you asked about is exactly similar;
it's just that you multiply by the amplitude factor $-1/2$ instead, to flip the wave upside down. (Since it starts out with $\sin^2 0 = 0 = 1/2 - 1/2$ instead of $\cos^2 0 = 1 = 1/2 + 1/2$.)